# Binding Of Isaac Judas Unlock Problem

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

To unlock Judas I need to kill Satan. But I have killed Satan like three times (as Azazel) and I still haven't unlocked Judas. What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried with a different character?

Comment: Just to be clear, did you kill Satan by completing Sheol, which is reached by going down from the Womb?

Comment: @Joe Try to beat Satan with normal Isaac

Answer (score 3):

As per BoI:R Wikia:

> Judas is a character unlocked after beating Satan for the first time.

However, there are some limitations. Are you sure that...

- you weren't on seed run? Seed runs (when you enter the seed to a certain level) do not unlock new characters/items/achievements.
- it was Satan? There are few enemies who look like Satan but they aren't, i.e. The Fallen One or Krampus. The Satan you need to kill is a final boss of Sheol level and it's the only place where you can find him.